# Select .bak file with latest timestamp

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, restore

I would like to restore a database backup file .bak to a server but there are a few .bak file with different timestamp, for example :

> dbname_backup_201210290200.bak
>   dbname_backup_201210300212.bak
>   dbname_backup_201210310213.bak

Comment: [Please don't use `varchar` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). Also, why do you need to do this from within T-SQL? PowerShell or C# are much better equipped at answering questions like "get me part of the filename from the latest file with a certain extension in a given folder."

Comment: This question is useless but still comes up in Google searches... smh

Answer (score 4):

Assuming xp_cmdshell is enabled and that all files will end with yyyyMMddhhmm.bak:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(n VARCHAR(2048));

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(2048), @fn VARCHAR(2048), @folder VARCHAR(255);

SET @folder = 'E:\sqlbackup\MerchantAPIReport\'; --'
SET @cmd = 'dir /b "' + @folder + 'MerchantAPIReport_backup_*.bak"';

INSERT #x EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;

SELECT TOP (1) @fn = @folder + n 
  FROM #x
  ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(RIGHT(n, 16), 12), 11, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ' '))
  DESC;

-- whatever you do, don't try to construct this yourself.
-- I'll fill in the blanks for you. <sigh>

RESTORE DATABASE [MerchantAPIReport] FROM DISK = @fn
  WITH FILE = 1,
  MOVE N'MerchantAPIReport'     TO N'D:\SQLData01\MerchantAPIReport.mdf',
  MOVE N'MerchantAPIReport_log' TO N'F:\SQLLog\MerchantAPIReport.ldf',
  NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10;

-- RESTORE DATABASE ... FROM @fn ...; -- fill in the rest here

DROP TABLE #x;
```

Comment: @user1484403 did you check that I copied your folder name correctly? Did you check what is contained in #x?

Comment: @user1484403 sorry, but I don't understand which part of your question you actually want to keep. If you just want the .bak file with the latest timestamp, the code I've provided should be all you need. If there are additional requirements you haven't stated, please state them or start a new question.

Comment: sorry i have juz edit to another version